# How to Find Class of + in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The design philosophy of ruby is just amazing. So I did `1 + 2` and got `3`. I managed to make this: `1.+(2) # => 3`.

As cool as this was, I also wanted to test out the `class` method on the `+` method.

```
+.class
=> SyntaxError: (irb):14: syntax error, unexpected '.'
   +.class
     ^
```

And then:

```
+().class
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `+@' for NilClass:Class
```

While:

```
+(2).class
NoMethodError: undefined method `+@' for Fixnum:Class
```

Why was `+(2).class` a fixnum and not an integer? I try it again with `+(2.to_i).class` and the same error appears for `+(2).class`.

But back to the key question: How do I find the class of the `+` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1 + 2` is calling the `+` method on `1` with `2` as an argument, which is the same as `1.+(2)`.

However, because of precedence, `+(2).class` is actually calling `(2).class` first, returning an instance of `Class`, then calling the nonexistent `+@` method, which is the unary plus method that only exists for `Numeric`. You can test this by typing `(+(2)).class`, which returns `Fixnum` as one would expect. This is also the source of the error for `+().class`, because `()` returns `nil`, and the class of `nil` is `NilClass`, which also doesn't have a `+@` method.

tl;dr: because precedence made the leading `+` evaluate last, as `+@`.

The `+` method on any object is of the class `Method`, as is any other method on any object. However, typing `+` calls the method instead of returning it, because Matz saw in a dream that a programming language that returns methods instead of calling them doesn't run. You can have the method returned to you by calling the `method` method with the method name, like so: `1.method(:+)`. Then you can make the method object tell you what its class is: `1.method(:+).class`.

Comment: I think I'll place you as the answer. You've explained why all my errors proved as they were. I'm assuming its impossible to bully Ruby into telling me that the class of `+` is obviously `Method`. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Not impossible! @Oxynum demonstrated it in his/her answer and I've added it to mine.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I find the class of the + method?

You can do it as below using [`#owner`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Method.html#method-i-owner) and [`#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-method) :

```
1.method(:+).owner # => Fixnum
'1'.method(:+).owner # => String
```

As above output clearly telling you, when you are doing `1 + 2` or `1.+(2)`, [`Fixnum#+`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-2B) method is being called. Similar way While you would write `'1' + '2'` or `'1'.+('2')`. [`String#+`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-2B) method is being called.

Comment: Starting to see what your answer is saying. Answer expands nicely after @jimworn's answer explained the errors and what was going on.

Comment: @BenMorganIO That's because I couldn't understand, you need the explanation of the *syntax error*. I thought your pain is *But back to the key question: How do I find the class of the + method?*.

Answer (score 2):

Simple :)

Try that :

```
m = 1.method("+")
m.class
```

Comment: No.. It is not.. `m.class` would give you `Method`.

Comment: Yes, precisely, so where is the problem ? The class of the + method is Method. 
What did you expect ?

Comment: Read question - OP wanted to know of which class's instance method is `#+`, when OP is trying `1.+(2)`.

Comment: I read : But back to the key question: How do I find the class of the + method?
My answer : The lass of the + method is `Method`
I'm really lost now.

Comment: Go ahead as you like.. You are making confused OP. See what *IRB* is telling `irb(main):001:0> 1.method(:+)
=> #<Method: Fixnum#+>`

Comment: First, what is OP ? And I'm just trying to understand, cause as I read and understand the question, my answer seems legit.

Comment: I think Oxynum has a better answer here. I wanted to know how to get the class of `+`. Since the `owner` method can give me several results, I don't trust it. I can see how it was easy to confuse. I wonder if there's a way to call the `method(:method)`... Anywho, since `1.method(:+).class` returns `Method`, that's nice, but how do I know if I'm not just calling class on `method` and not `+`? Because I'm suspecting `method` would return `Method`.

Comment: You just have to know that every method has the same class, and that class is `Method`

Comment: @BenMorganIO `:+` is not a method of `Method`. You are not on the correct track. `1.method(:+)` creating a `Method` object, thus `m.class` giving you `Method`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit , I actually do not understand if he is looking for the class that defines the method (the owner as you wrote) or if he is looking at the class of the + method...

Comment: The + method is defined in a lot of classes, `String` or `Fixnum` for example. The class of the + method is `Method`. `Method` is the class of every method. If you want to find the class where the + method is defined, then refer to @ArupRakshit answer.

Answer (score 1):

Methods aren't objects in Ruby, therefore they don't have a class. You can use reflection to obtain a proxy object that represents a method, though, in which case the class will either be `Method` or `UnboundMethod`, depending on whether the method is bound to a receiver object or not.